# Install mCrypt on CENTOS 5.8 x86_64

Tags: mcrypt

Having some problems installing this and thought I'd post again. I try yum install php-mcrypt* or yum install php-mcrypt and it says no package available.

I tried installing EPL with su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm' and it said "transfered failed".

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So you're following the instructions available from [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F) regarding how to install that repository so you'll have access to it? Troubleshooting wise did you start with a  yum clean all (you will need sudo access for that), then a yum list php-mcrypt? If so and there were no results returned you'll need to review your server to ensure it's configured properly, can you even ping download.fedoraproject.org? Can you reach it with a curl? Past that I'm not quite sure why the transfer would fail with the error you have provided, we'd need to see the full output when you run the command (I assume you do have sudo privileges correct?) If you just want to pull down that rpm you could always find it and just run a wget, then manually install with RPM itself.

While that will get you the RPM (if you can access the host), it will pose problems going forward, how do you upgrade the RPM and know when to do so? If we automate the system will this RPM get updated when a new version is released? How do we keep track of which version is supposed to go on what server? How do we prevent configuration drift? While these questions are pretty high level, it's important to consider them. I would suggest you begin by reviewing your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory to see what repo files already exist, and exploring the repos contained in those files (this will allow you to review their structure to determine if the RPM you need is simply in a different directory), both as a learning experience and as a way to understand how the repo file is organized. While you're doing that review [the Fedora docs on configuring Yum, and Yum repos](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html), or the docs for your distro. This should allow you to properly determine which repo this RPM is coming from, add a repo file that will provide you the ability to keep relevant updates, and then install the RPM via YUM.